# javascript group unique items in array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I have an array in the below format.

```
    var produce = [
        {'supplierID':1,'produceID':1, 'name':'apple', 'qty': 10},
        {'supplierID':1,'produceID':2, 'name':'carrot', 'qty': 10},
        {'supplierID':1,'produceID':2, 'name':'bean', 'qty': 20},
        {'supplierID':1,'produceID':1, 'name':'bananna', 'qty': 30},
        {'supplierID':1,'produceID':1, 'name':'orange', 'qty': 65},
        {'supplierID':2,'produceID':2, 'name':'pumpkin', 'qty': 120},
        {'supplierID':2,'produceID':2, 'name':'cucumber', 'qty': 18},
        {'supplierID':2,'produceID':1, 'name':'strawberry', 'qty': 130},
        {'supplierID':2,'produceID':1, 'name':'mango', 'qty': 60},
        {'supplierID':2,'produceID':1, 'name':'grapes', 'qty': 140}
    ];
//produceID 1 = fruit
//produceID 2 = veg
```

I want it in this sort of format.

```
    {
        'id': 1,
        'fruit': [
            {
                'name': 'apple',
                'qty': 10
            },
            {
                'name': 'bananna',
                'qty': 30
            },
            {
                'name': 'orange',
                'qty': 65
            }        
        ],
        'veg': [
            {
                'name': 'carrot',
                'qty': 10
            },
            {
                'name': 'bean',
                'qty': 20
            },        
        ]
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'fruit': [
            {
                'name': 'strawberry',
                'qty': 130
            },
            {
                'name': 'mango',
                'qty': 60
            },
            {
                'name': 'grapes',
                'qty': 140
            }        
        ],
        'veg': [
            {
                'name': 'pumpkin',
                'qty': 120
            },
            {
                'name': 'cucumber',
                'qty': 18
            },        
        ]
    }
```

So that I can group my items first by supplier then by produce type (fruit/veg) (using angular js)

```
      <div style="width:100%" ng-repeat="res in results">
        <h2>Supplier - {{res.id}}</h2>
        <h3>Fruit</h3>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="f in res.fruit">{{f.name}}</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Veg</h3>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="v in res.veg">{{v.name}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

A working eg of this can be seen in this codepen. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVVJjg

How can I achieve this?

So far I have found that I need to find all suppliers which I can with the below.

```
//get unique suppliers
var unique = {};
var distinct = [];
    for( var i in produce ){
     if( typeof(unique[produce[i].supplierID]) == "undefined"){
      distinct.push(produce[i].supplierID);
     }
     unique[produce[i].supplierID] = 0;
    }
console.log(distinct);
```

I can also get the right format for supplierID == 1 as shown below, but not sure how I could scale this to handle multiple suppliers

```
var fruit = [];
var veg = [];
var res = [];
for (var i in produce) {

    if (produce[i].supplierID == 1) {
      if (produce[i].produceID == 1) {
          fruit.push(produce[i]);
      }
      else {
          veg.push(produce[i]);
      }
    }
}

res.push(fruit);
res.push(veg);
console.log(res);
```

How can I acheive this?

Comment: How would you decide between fruit and veg? For example a tomato is a fruit :)]

Comment: Don't use your own loops, use `sort`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```js
var produce = [
        {'supplierID':1,'produceID':1, 'name':'apple', 'qty': 10},
        {'supplierID':1,'produceID':2, 'name':'carrot', 'qty': 10},
        {'supplierID':1,'produceID':2, 'name':'bean', 'qty': 20},
        {'supplierID':1,'produceID':1, 'name':'bananna', 'qty': 30},
        {'supplierID':1,'produceID':1, 'name':'orange', 'qty': 65},
        {'supplierID':2,'produceID':2, 'name':'pumpkin', 'qty': 120},
        {'supplierID':2,'produceID':2, 'name':'cucumber', 'qty': 18},
        {'supplierID':2,'produceID':1, 'name':'strawberry', 'qty': 130},
        {'supplierID':2,'produceID':1, 'name':'mango', 'qty': 60},
        {'supplierID':2,'produceID':1, 'name':'grapes', 'qty': 140}
    ];


res = [];
suppliers = {};
for (var i in produce) {
 product = produce[i];       
 var supplier = suppliers[product.supplierID]
 if (!supplier) {
  supplier = {id: product.supplierID, fruit: [], veg: []};
  suppliers[product.supplierID] = supplier;
  res.push(supplier);
 }

 if (product.produceID == 1) {    
  supplier.fruit.push({name: product.name, qty: product.qty});
 } else if (product.produceID == 2) {    
  supplier.veg.push({name: product.name, qty: product.qty});
 }
};
console.log(res);
```